# Assertion error, string subscript out of range

Tags: c++, assertion

I almost have this menu done and working the way I want it to.  However, I get an assertion error when I press Enter without inputting anything.  Here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>


using namespace std;

bool menu ()
{
 string input = "";
 bool exitVar;

 do
 {
 system("cls");

 cout << "               _       _   _   _       _   _ _ _  " << endl
      << "              |_|_   _|_| |_| |_|_    |_| |_|_|_| " << endl
      << "              |_|_|_|_|_| |_| |_|_|_  |_| |_|_    " << endl
      << "              |_| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_|_|_| |_|_|   " << endl
      << "              |_|     |_| |_| |_|   |_|_| |_|_ _  " << endl
      << "              |_|     |_| |_| |_|     |_| |_|_|_| " << endl
      << "               _ _   _       _   _ _ _   _ _ _   _ _     _ _ _   _ _      " << endl
      << "             _|_|_| |_|     |_| |_|_|_| |_|_|_| |_|_|_  |_|_|_| |_|_|_    " << endl
      << "            |_|_    |_|  _  |_| |_|_    |_|_    |_|_|_| |_|_    |_|_|_|   " << endl
      << "              |_|_  |_|_|_|_|_| |_|_|   |_|_|   |_|_|   |_|_|   |_|_|_    " << endl
      << "             _ _|_| |_|_| |_|_| |_|_ _  |_|_ _  |_|     |_|_ _  |_| |_|_  " << endl
      << "            |_|_|   |_|     |_| |_|_|_| |_|_|_| |_|     |_|_|_| |_|   |_| " << endl;

 cout << "\n            Welcome to Psuedo Mine Sweeper!!\n\n\n\n";

 cout << "                  <S>TART"
     << "\n\n                   <E>XIT\n\n";



    cout << "\t\t\tPlease enter a valid menu option: ";
    getline(cin,input);

    input[0] = toupper(input[0]);

}while(input[0] != 'S' && input[0] != 'E' || input.length() != 1 || cin.peek() != '\n');

if (input[0] == 'S')
    exitVar = true;
else
    exitVar = false;

return exitVar;
```

}

I'm not too experienced with debugging assertion values.  I tried running the menu standalone

Comment: Try to print input after getline and you will probably see the problem!

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that when you press enter `getline` sets `input` to an empty string since no input was entered.

This means it has length 0, but when you call `input[0]` you are asking for the first character in it. Since it doesn't have one, it throws an assertion error.

To fix this, after calling `getline` check to see if `input` is empty, if it is, use `continue` to start the loop over again.

Comment: Ahhhhh, that makes sense.  If I change the definition of "string input" to some value rather than leaving it blank, will that fix the issue.  Gonna try it out now, just speculating.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Nope, didn't work....hmmmm.  I guess that won't work because when I try to getline it redefines the string as empty if enter is pushed.  How can I get around this?

Comment: Check to see if the string is empty, if it is call `continue`. This will pop you out of the current iteration of the loop and start again

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your loop condition.

`while (input.length() != 1 || (toupper(input[0]) != 'S' && toupper(input[0]) != 'E'));`

`||` is tested left to right, so you must check the length is the correct value *before* you check the first character. It will also help to do `toupper` as part of the loop condition since this way the check on the length happens first. I removed the call to `cin.peek()` as well, not sure I understand what that was about.

You could rewrite the whole thing with a bit of boolean logic to make it clearer.

`while (!(input.length() == 1 && (toupper(input[0]) == 'S' || toupper(input[0]) == 'E')));`

Generally the fewer negations there are the easier complex boolean logic is to understand.

Comment: He also calls input[0] before the loop condition

Comment: So he does. I'll amend my answer.

Comment: Fixed it!  Did what you said and removed the part where I called input[0] before the loop.  Good to know that while loops execute left to right, skipped my mind.  Thanks so much guys!

Comment: @DustinBurns Not while loops, `||` and also `&&`. `||` and `&&` are special in this regard, most operators do not work like that.